# Submitting two forms with one button click in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, forms

I have two forms in two different Views in my MVC web application:

First form in first view, its a dropdownlist and it's id is "ddlform":

```
    @model BTSWeb.Models.DropDownModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ddlform" }))
{
            <span style="margin-left:-255px;margin-top:5em"></span>  

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId, Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.States)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.States), e)).ToString()}),new { style = "width: 60px;font-size:105%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px;padding-left:5px"})

<input type="submit" id="submit-form" value="Submit"  hidden="hidden"  />

}
```

Form in my second view with id "serverform" and two text boxes:

```
  @model BTSWeb.Models.DropDownModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="serverform"}))
{
        <label style="color:black">    Type the name of the server you want to use.                 
       </label>
        <span style="margin-left:80px"></span>  

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server1)
    <br/><br/>
                   <span style="padding-top:2px"></span> 
    <label style="color:black">    If you wish you compare the results from two  servers. Type the name of second server:
    </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server2)
        }
```

A button to submit these two forms in the second view bound to a JS function:

```
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Find Billable Account" onclick="submitForms()" />
```

Finally the JS function, also in the second view:

```
 <script>
function submitForms() {
    document.getElementById("serverform").submit();

    document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();


}
 </script>
```

The problem is only ddl form is being submitted and not the other form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form the current page STOPS EXECUTION, then the server spits out a new page. It's just like navigating away, except you're sending the for data to the server along with the request. Therefore you cannot submit two forms on the same page.

You can either:

1) Submit one or both forms using AJAX

or

2) Target each form to its own Iframe, and handle the response in the Iframe yourself.